# tricky huffman tree issue

Tags: tree, huffman-code

I'm wondering how to create the following tree using the sum of `rows` and `columns`, for example, the numbers on ( ) are the probability

```
C (0.056)   O (0.076)   G (0.020)   P (0.019)   A (0.081)   B (0.041)   
H (0.034)   D (0.030)   E (0.115)   F (0.027)   I (0.028)   J (0.002)   
K (0.005)   L (0.038)   M (0.018)   N (0.070)   Q (0.0008)  R (0.063)   
£ (0.064)   * (0.100)   - (0.029)   = (0.009)   + (0.016)   % (0.012)
```

Each row is totalled at the end of each row, and each column is totalled at the bottom.Using the rows and columns totals to create a tree that will be able to find for example the letter `M` which is in column 3 row 3.

Thanks for any possible help.

Comment: made a few changes to possible help understand..

Answer (score 0):

You would make two Huffman codes, one with six symbols for the columns and one with four symbols for the rows, using the respective probabilities of each. Each letter would be coded with one of each code.

However this is a dumb idea, as you would get better compression using a single Huffman code with 24 symbols.